# How to prevent browser fingerprinting accoss VM's whilst remaining natural?

Tags: web-browser, fingerprinting

I am using a couple VM's fitted with proxies and find that browser fingerprinting across VM's causes me many issues. I also have issue with the browser created inside VM leaking that I am using VM. May seem like a n00b question, but is anyone able to give insight into the best setup for using multiple VM device browsers without 1 - allowing the website to identify I am using a virtual machine / appear like a natural user and 2 - prevent links between 2 or more separate VM browsers e.g through browser fingerprinting or other methods?

*Apologies for spelling written quickly on phone

Comment: please post more info: what browser, what environment?

Comment: Newest chrome, VMware. Have tested with other browsers / new VM instances and feel like issue I am facing is down to browser fingerprint detection issues e.g WebGL, WebRTC and other things which if are hard to spoof apparently but disabling them makes me look unnatural as 99% of internet have it up lol

Comment: yep you're fighting an uphill battle - there are plug-ins to disrupt *ever so slightly* the canvas fingerprinting, disable audio, disable webrtc, disable 3rd-party domain **anything**, use a good blocker such as *uBlock* or *uMatrix*, disable auto-update, configure a user-agent spoofer, fix your window's size to prevent aperture/ resolution fingerprinting, use a paid-for vpn, ... *<takes a deep breath>* did i miss anything!? (yep, safebrowsing and other 'potentially unwanted anyhthing')

Comment: Using a couple VMs is not the solution to avoid _fingerprinting_ It is also not practical to avoid fingerprinting from *all* the sites that you visit. Every site can potentially use a different set of parameters to fingerprint and so it is more practical to target 1-2 (or a few sites), study them well to see how they fingerprint and then create a strategy to bypass that.